# Conditional Formatting with Date Condition and Text Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight certain cells in red if the date in Column X is older than 14 days AND if the answer in Column U is "No".
If The answer in Column U is "Yes" I want the cells in Column X to remain with "Normal" formatting irrespective of the date.

What I have identifies dates older than 14 days, ignores blanks and highlights in red. Problem is it isn't accounting for the answer in Column U.

```vb
    Dim Overdue As Range

    Set Overdue = Worksheets("Progress").Range("X3:X3000")
    Overdue.FormatConditions.Delete
    'Add error rule for dates more than 14 days old
    Overdue.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($X3)), Now()-X3 > 14)"
    'Sets cell background colour
    Overdue.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13551615
End Sub
```

I attempted multiple solutions. I can either always format in red or always format in white. Even "If" conditionals don't work.

I need to use VBA to resolve the issue. If I simply apply conditional formatting, the formatting gets wiped out as I am copying data from another worksheet onto this one.

Comment: My guess would be `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($X3)), Now()-X3 > 14, U3 = "No")` It would be useful to see some of what you have tried

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried so many alternatives and have lost track of it all. I'm still relatively new to VBA so it is a bit difficult for me to keep on top of the different methods.

Comment: If you use conditional formatting: Is there a reason to set this via VBA?

Comment: The way this sheet works is that it copies information from another sheet over to it when a button is clicked based on certain criteria. However, when pasting using VBA, it always removes the Conditional Formatting that I apply to the sheet. I don't know if there is a way to preserve conditional formatting using VBA when pasting into a cell.

Comment: Instead of Pasting you could write the data directly (using the `value`-property)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub ColorOldItems()
Dim i As Long
Dim xarr

Worksheets("Progress").Range("X3:X3000").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
xarr = Worksheets("Progress").Range("U3:X3000").Value

For i = 1 To UBound(xarr)
If IsDate(xarr(i, 4)) And xarr(i, 4) < Date - 14 And xarr(i, 1) = "No" Then Worksheets("Progress").Cells(i + 2, 24).Interior.Color = 13551615
Next i
End Sub
```